# Transferring iTunes library from an old HDD

Tags: itunes, windows, ssd, hdd

I have recently purchased a new PC and connected my old SSD and HDD to the new PC.

My old HDD has my iTunes library that I would like to transfer to my new PC, however since I cannot boot my old SSD (it is running an old version of windows and I do not have the drivers installed for the new PC) how would I be able to transfer my iTunes?

The following files are the only ones I have access to. Would it be possible to import my iTunes library using one of these files? Or is backing up the old library the only way of doing so?

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Trying to run the iTunes file in this folder pulls up an error stating please reinstall iTunes since this version of iTunes was for Win8 and my new PC is running Win10

Answer (score 1):

1. You're looking in the wrong place. You will need to drill down into the old drive from the top… D drive (or whatever letter it has) Users\your old user name\ Music\iTunes. Copy or move to the same relative location in your new C drive.

   Install [iTunes](https://support.apple.com/HT210384) afresh. It should then find it automatically.
2. You can't launch an app that wasn't installed on your current C drive, as it doesn't know where to look for additional libraries needed to run. Once you've installed it correctly on your new computer you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, should I move the folder before installing iTunes or install iTunes then move the folder?

Comment: I'd move it first, that way iTunes should find it as you install. the other way round you may hit conflicts as some data would already have been created in that location. For safety, I'd probably **copy** the data rather than move; make sure everything works properly before deleting the old location.